# How to avoid the duplication is css?

Tags: html, css

How to avoid the following CSS duplication:

```css
div#logo div:nth-child(1) div {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: white;
}

div#logo div:nth-child(3) div {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this for 1,3,5,7....like `div:nth-child(2n+1)` start with 2(0)+1=1 then add 2(1)+1 = 3,2(2)+1=5 cont...

```css
div#logo div:nth-child(2n+1) div{
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this keyword `2n+1` @Gattbha

Comment: Yes sure @Ilyaskarim

Comment: @Ilyaskarim Check now

Answer (score 4):

You can combine the statements, like this:

```css
div#logo div:nth-child(1) div, div#logo div:nth-child(3) div{
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
div#logo div:nth-child(odd) div {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to search similar or duplicated css classes in your project. You can use this from GitHub: [css-checker](https://github.com/ruilisi/css-checker).

The above tool can scan all your css files and find those who share similarly >= 80% and point out the diff from each other.